# Error when unit testing Angular service decorated with Injectable

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner, injectable

I have an angular service, very simple inside. I wrote couple of unit tests and my Jasmine/Karma runner throws errors lile:

```
Uncaught TypError: (0, tslib_WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.__decorate) is not a function...
```

After some investigation I discovered that commenting out the Injectable decorator above the Service class fixes everything. Any idea what the problem might be?